# UI doesnt render when i use Navigation Drawer in my android app

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer

i want to use Navigation Drawer in my app. according google documentation here, i write my UI code like this:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <!-- The main content view -->


<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" > 

        MAIN LAYOUT IS HERE 

</FrameLayout>  

<!-- The navigation drawer -->
 <ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
     android:layout_width="240dp"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:layout_gravity="start"
     android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
     android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
     android:dividerHeight="0dp"
     android:background="#111"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

this is like google's own example but it gives me an error in layout preview:

```
Exception raised during rendering: DrawerLayout must be measured with MeasureSpec.EXACTLY.
```

i searched a lot about it, some people says that you have to put explicit values for android:layout_width and android:layout_height. when i do this everything is going to be OK but i dont want to put explicit values! because i dont know every device  width and height... how i can fix that? whats the solution?

i already put android-support-v4.jar file in lib folder. i think its the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

just right click on project >> select android tool >> select add support library .

this should work , just do same steps !